# HTML5 database saved details along with a button

Tags: javascript, database, cordova, button

I am developing an app in Phone gap.. where I am saving all the details of employees including there date of birth and address. In one page I have a save button and recall button. When user press the entered details should be saved... and this is working fine. when user press the recall button this saved details should be display.. when showing this only their names will display and a button will be there in each row. By pressing this button next to the name ..he should able to select the particular row only..

my problem I am not able to display button on each row... button is displaying only after all row.. that means only one button.. but I need one button after each row for selecting that particular row.. I am giving my code below.. I f anyone know how to code it pls help..

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/recallpage.css" />        
<title>Hello World</title>   
</head> 
<body onload="onLoad();">    
<div class="app"> 
<label id="naming">Name</label>
<br>
<br>

<label id="listing"></label>
<input id="btn1" class="cls_btn" type="submit" name="btn" value="Find" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>        
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      app.initialize();
    function onLoad() {
     var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
            db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
    }

    // Transaction error callback
    function errorCB(tx, err) {
        alert("Error processing SQL: " + err);
    }

     // Query the database
        //
        function queryDB(tx) {
      tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);

        }

        // Query the success callback
        //
        function querySuccess(tx, results) {
            var x = document.getElementById("listing");
            var len = results.rows.length;
            for (var i=0; i<len; i++){

    var searchBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('cls_btn');

    x.innerHTML  +=results.rows.item(i).data +  results.rows.item(i).data2 + "      " +  searchBtn+ "<br />" ;
            }
        }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var b = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var t = document.createTextNode("Select");    
    b.appendChild(t);    
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row  = table.insertRow(counter);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);    
    cell1.innerHTML = results.rows.item(i).data;
    cell2.innerHTML = results.rows.item(i).data2;
    cell3.appendChild(b);  
     b.onclick = function()
     { 

and you can whatever you need on clicking button here
}
counter++; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is because Google Chrome lets not read files from your hard drive itself ... I think if you allow Firefox to run your example correctly :)